# Hello I am getting an error in my kotlin file that is" :app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest" . can any help me

Tags: kotlin

```
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
```

I tried to solve the error by searching in Google,but i didn't found a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

1.Check for errors in the AndroidManifest.xml file: Open the AndroidManifest.xml file in Android Studio and make sure there are no syntax errors or missing required elements.

2. Clean and rebuild your project: Sometimes, build errors can be resolved by simply cleaning and rebuilding your project. To do this, go to "Build" > "Clean Project" and then "Build" > "Rebuild Project".
3. Check for conflicting dependencies: If you have recently added new dependencies to your project, it is possible that there is a conflict between them. You can try to resolve this by using the ./gradlew app:dependencies command to see a list of all the dependencies in your project and check for any conflicts.